# Placing a react-native-video inside FlatList then pressing a button to go full screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

Say I have a react native app with a FlatList. Inside the FlatList is a react-native-video component. The video is hosted online. Inside the FlatList the video can be played. What I want is also a button that can be pressed and the video should go full screen. Is this possible to do without having to reload the video?

One solution I can do is when the button is pressed a new screen shows (e.g. in StackNavigator) with the video using flex:1 to fill up the screen. However, because it is a new screen the video needs to load again.

I've seen the Reddit app be able to bring up a video full screen without having to reload it. Of course this might be a native app and harder to do in react native.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this in react native?

EDIT: Added extra info.

Comment: Reload? You wanted to cache it so would get rid of to re buffer again?

Comment: Yes. Also the video is hosted online so it is not a local file.

Comment: You would have to locally cache it after downloading from the network and play if it caches so it will take time first when caching but afterwards, will play without buffering from local.